# Hiding and showing divs depending on variable value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, show

Can anyone please tell me why the code below is not showing the div ticker? it just shows div main ..

Thanks a lot!

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 


        $('.ticker').hide();
        $('.main').show();
        $('.other').hide();

    }) 
</script>
<?php

$main = 'ticker';

if ($main=="ticker"){?>
    <script type="text/javascript"> //alert('flag'); //this alert shows ok
        $('.ticker').show();
        $('.main').hide();
        $('.other').hide();
    </script>
    <?php


}

?>
<div class="main">main</div>
<div class="ticker">ticker</div>
<div class="other">other</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the `$(document).ready()` from the second script block.

Comment: thanks, worked! didn't know you needed $(document).ready() even when the page was already loaded.

Comment: It likely would have worked if you had the script block placed under the elements you are attempting to query, but as the elements are not yet on the page when you were attempting to query them, the javascript was failing. It's best practice to wrap all jQuery (and javascript for that matter) in a page load wrapper.

Comment: @teresko if the second script block was placed under the divs, without the $(document).ready() wrapping it, it would still work properly, as all the elements trying to be accessed by the javascript have already been written to the DOM. However, it wouldn't seem like that was the case, as the first script block would execute after page load and override them.

Comment: That why it is recommended to **include** the **external** javascript file right before the closing </body>. Then you don't have to care about onDomReady event.

Answer (score 1):

The first script block says "When the document is ready, show and hide the elements with these classes".

The second script block says "Show and hide the elements with these classes **immediately**".

At the time the second script block is executed, there are no elements with those classes (so it has no effect). Even if there were, the first script block would override them a few seconds later.

You probably want to do something like:

```
<?php
    $main = 'ticker';
?>
<div class="main">main</div>
<div class="ticker">ticker</div>
<div class="other">other</div>
<script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $('.ticker, .main, .other').hide();
        $('.<?php echo $main ?>').show();
    }) 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php    
$main = 'ticker';    
if ($main=="ticker"){?>
<script type="text/javascript"> //alert('flag'); //this alert shows ok
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.ticker').show();
        $('.main').hide();
        $('.other').hide();
    });
</script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks Starx, but I need to have the ticker hidden when the page frist loads and the main showing. That's why I was using that code.

Answer (score 0):

a bit nicer ;)

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function(){
        $('.hide').hide();
        $('.show').show();
    });
</script>
<?php
$main = 'ticker';
?>
<div class="main <?php echo ($main == 'main') ? 'show' : 'hide'; ?>">main</div>
<div class="ticker <?php echo ($main == 'ticker') ? 'show' : 'hide'; ?>">ticker</div>
<div class="other <?php echo ($main == 'other') ? 'show' : 'hide'; ?>">other</div>
```